# Looping through rows of Selection | Range vs Rows

Tags: excel, vba, range, type-mismatch

I've got a class Portal with a

```
Public Function Init(Rng As Range) As Portal
```

Which processes the first 2 cells of the Rng range, using Rng.Item(1) and Rng.Item(2). This works fine for the first row of a selection:

```
Sub ProcessPortal()
    Dim mPortal As Portal

    Set mPortal = New Portal
    With mPortal
        .Init Selection
    End With

End Sub
```

But it fails when I want to loop through the rest of the rows:

```
Sub ProcessPortal()
    Dim mPortal As Portal
    Dim a As Range, b As Range

    Set a = Selection
    For Each b In a.Rows
        Set mPortal = New Portal
        With mPortal
            .Init b
        End With
    Next b
End Sub
```

b is a Range, just like Selection, right? Why do I get a type mismatch on .Init b?

Comment: Use `Cells(1)` and `Cells(2)` instead of `Item(1)` and `Item(2)`.  There are various "flavours" of `Range` objects and the `Item` property will return different things in different cases.  (E.g. `Item(1)` of a row is the row.)

Comment: Awesome, that worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to access cells, use the `Cells` property of the `Range` object, rather than the `Item` property, i.e. use `Cells(1)` and `Cells(2)` in your `Init` procedure.

The first `Item` of an entire row is the row itself, as can be seen by:

```
Debug.Print Rows(1).Item(1).Address
```

which will return `$1:$1` while

```
Debug.Print Rows(1).Cells(1).Address
```

will return `$A$1`.